# More than 1500 proxyes with JMS transport, WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 and Activemq

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic, wso2-esb

Is there developers who have been succeeded deployed to wso2 esb more than 1500 proxy services 
with jms transport without any problems?

Criteria:

- deploying process must be very fast
- wso2esb use activemq client libraries and activemq brocker

someone please help me!

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible. There is no limitation on the number of proxies that an ESB can have. 
You may try this with using the hot deployment capabilities of WSO2 ESB.

You may create a bunch of proxy services and place them inside:
/repository/deployment/server/synapse-config/default/proxy-services

Then the proxies with get automatically deployed..

eg:

proxy_1.xml, proxy_2.xml, proxy_3.xml,..., proxy_1500.xml etc.

However, having this number of proxy services, gives some indication of some anti-pattern in your SOA. Please review whether you need this much of proxy services in your solution architecture.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!
I have been tested WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 with some my customizations in activemq client libraries and axis2 jms transport.
I have 1500 queues and I need to deploy 1500 proxyes with jms transport to create 1500 jms consumers.

Process of deploying proxy (when 1500 proxyes with jms transport) in esb and creation jms consumers for proxy in esb and in the broker takes more than 1 hour.


How to accelerate this process?  Or maybe I not correctly do it .. ?
Do you have some ideas about this issue?

Comment: You can either write a script or a small java program to generate the proxy services(simply generate set of xml files) and then hot deploy them by just putting in to the proxy-services folder. Deploying that much of proxies will take some time tough. BTW, any thoughts on revisiting your solution architecture.